# Linear Program Phase 1 first pivot doesn't provide a starting dictionary

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method, two-phase-simplex

I have the LP and need to solve it using the two phase simplex algorithm, not the dual two phase;

$$\max\quad4x_1 - 3x_2 + 6x_3$$
$$\text{Subject to: }\quad x_1 +  x_2         \le -4$$
$$\text{ }\qquad\qquad\quad x_2 +  x_3   \le -6$$
$$\quad\qquad x_3   \le  6$$

When I transform this into an auxiliary problem;
$$\max zeta =\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad$$
$$\text{S.T }\quad x_4 = -4 - x_1 - x_2      + x_0$$
$$x_5 = -6      - x_2 - x_3 + x_0$$
$$x_6 =  6             x_3 + x_0$$

And do my first pivot step with $x_0$ entering the basis and $x_5$ leaving the basis (because its the most negative coefficient).

I end up with the objective function being zeta $= -6 -x_2 -x_3 -x_5$, which doesn't allow me to carry on the simplex algorithm.

Comment: I guess you should phrase a proper question to answer to. But if you have an LP with a negative start solution there is for example the BigM method or Dantzig's method. Sometimes it is also possible to consider the dual problem instead. If you do some research on this topics I'm sure you come up with a solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, Ill update my question. 
I have been told to complete this question using only what we have learn; which is transforming the problem into an auxiliary problem and using the 2 phase method.

Comment: The 2 phase method is the same as the above mentioned Dantzig method. This should do the trick here.

Answer (score 1):

I’m unsure if those variables are supposed to be non-negative or unsigned, so we’re going to proceed for both cases:

**Unsigned Model to Two-Phase:**

Suppose we have the original model,
$$\max\quad z=4x_1-3x_2+6x_3$$
Subject to,
$$x_1+x_2\le-4$$
$$x_2+x_3\le-6$$
$$x_3\le6$$

We’ll need to make the right-hand-side non-negative such that we have $\ge$ constraints for artificial variables:

$$\max\quad z=4x_1-3x_2+6x_3$$
Subject to,
$$-x_1-x_2\ge4$$
$$-x_2-x_3\ge6$$
$$x_3\le6$$

Of course, since this is unsigned, we’ll need to substitute a $x_j=x_j^{’}-x^{ ’’}_j$ for every unsigned variable in the program. So, we’ll have the following model:

$$\max\quad z=4x_1^{'}-4x_1^{''}-3x_2^{'}+3x_2{''}+6x_3^{'}-6x_3^{''}$$
Subject to,
$$-x_1^{'}+x_1^{''}-x_2^{'}+x_2^{''}\ge4$$
$$-x^{'}_2+x^{''}_2-x^{'}_3+x^{''}_3\ge6$$
$$x^{'}_3-x^{''}_3\le6$$
$$x_1^{'},x_1^{''}, x_2^{'},x_2^{''}, x_3^{'},x_3^{''} \ge0$$

The standardized form of this model in the two phase approach would be:
$$\min w= a_1+a_2$$
Subject to,
$$-x_1^{'}+x_1^{''}-x_2^{'}+x_2^{''}-e_1+a_1=4$$
$$-x^{'}_2+x^{''}_2-x^{'}_3+x^{''}_3-e_2+a_2=6$$
$$x^{'}_3-x^{''}_3+s_3=6$$
$$x_1^{'},x_1^{''}, x_2^{'},x_2^{''}, x_3^{'},x_3^{''}, e_1, e_2,a_1,a_2,s_3\ge0$$

**NOTE:** Once this model has been solved, be sure to remember to plug in the values we got for $x_1^{'}\ldots x_3^{'’}$ back into their original substitutions to figure out the actual values for $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$. For example, suppose we got $x_1^{''}=7$ and $x_1^{'}=3$ for the final output from the Simplex algorithm, then $x_1=3-7=-4$.

**Non-Negative Model to Two-Phase**

If the non-negative constraints were forgotten, then the model will go as follows:
$$\max\quad z=4x_1-3x_2+6x_3$$
Subject to,
$$-x_1-x_2\ge4$$
$$-x_2-x_3\ge6$$
$$x_3\le6$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

Which will standardize into:

$$\min\quad w=a_1+a_2$$
Subject to,
$$-x_1-x_2-e_1+a_1=4$$
$$-x_2-x_3-e_2+a_2=6$$
$$x_3+s_3=6$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,e_1,e_2,a_1,a_2,s_3\ge0$$

**In Either**

In either approach, once we standardize the models, we’ll need to load them into their initial tableaus and solve for $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be our initial basic variables. Once both $a_1,a_2=0$, we’ll drop their respective columns and rows and proceed with Simplex normally as we would. From here, we’ll leave solving the rest of the model to the reader.

Comment: I excluded the upper-bound steps for $x_3$ by using the $s_3$ slack instead, but if we wanted to make the problem harder for ourselves, we can go about using the steps for upper-bounded variables to solve this on top of either mentioned approach